# Strategies to upload data to Redis cache

Tags: data-extraction, amazon-elasticache

I have 4 millions user data that is looked up by their phone number.  Source data is in S3. Search response time is 50 millisec and system need to be available 99.995%.

I am thinking about a nightly job like below
`S3 Source Data -> Glue ETL -> CSV file or RDS -> Cache Upload job -> AWS Redis global datastore`

I am leaning towards RDS since in case upload job fails for some reason I don't want to restart from beginning. Every row uploaded to Redis will be mark as processed.

I was planning to do an initial load of data from S3 to Redis and then do incremental load from thereafter.  The data team has informed me that they can't produce the incremental data, in other words they can't tell me what data changed yesterday.

As a result, every day I will have to empty the Redis cache and reload the entire data.  Since this upload will take considerable time, I am wondering how to keep the response time to 50 ms while data is loading.

Will appreciate any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: A pipe mass insert should in theory be able to handle 4M rows in a few seconds. Which makes me think that you could go Glue ETL direct to AWS Redis. But I, for the life of me, can't seem to find any way to have Glue do a pipe mass insert. Have you?

Comment: @Trip - thanks for the reply.  No I haven't. That's why I introduced a staging database to hold the result data.  But your comment about pipe mass insert gave me some idea.  I want to try "cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe" where data.txt holds the output from the Glue job.

Comment: Another option is use AWS Glue to write a custom Py script to write the format as your `data.txt` file. It supposedly offers that as a Target among its others ( CSV, JSON, ORC, etc. ). But I havn't messed with it yet. My second recommend would be to let AWS Glue do a vanilla JSON export, and write a RedisJSON script to consume. Third option is to skip Glue, and let BQ write the Redis code by virtue of fancy select statements. Then you run a remote docker redis machine to consume it.